# Double being cast to int returns 0

Tags: java

For a program, I need to find the length of a side of a polygon inscribed in circle, and then multiply that length by 2/3. I need the resulting value to be an integer, but when I try to cast the double to an int, it always returns 0.

Code:

```
double sideLength=428*Math.sin(Math.PI/4); 
int panelLength=(int)((2/3)*sideLength);
System.out.println(panelLength);
```

Output:

```
0
```

Multiplying `sideLength` by 2/3 and then casting it to an int is returning 0, but I want 201. The value of `sideLength` is correct. How do I fix this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem lies in this line:

```
int panelLength=(int)((2/3)*sideLength);
```

To be exact: `(2/3)` is an Integer division and will return an Integer. Therefore, `(2/3)` will yield the result `0`. And as we all know `anything * 0 == 0`.

You can fix this by making at least one of the values a double: `(2.0/3)` or `(2/3.0)` or `(2.0/3.0)` or `(2d/3)` or ...